# XSLT : Why doesn't this produce an empty document

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have an XSLT file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="/RESULTS">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and a sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report>
  <RESULTS>
       SOME DATA
  </RESULTS>
</Report>
```

When I run the transform I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

       SOME DATA
```

The template match clause is looking for /RESULTS and the root element in the data is Report, so the template never matches anything, so why is it returning all the text from the source file despite not matching any templates?

I've tested this with Saxon and .Net's XSLT 1.0 engine and the results are the same, so I guess its deliberate, but I can't find anything that describes the behaviour.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule

Comment: Thanks, that explains it!

Answer (score 1):

The core problem here is that your template rule with `match="/RESULTS"` only matches a `RESULTS` element at the outermost level of the document (without the leading `/`, it would match anywhere). So the template rule doesn't match anything, which means all the elements in your source are processed by the built-in template rules, including the text nodes, which are simply copied to the result.